# JPA relationships cause my JSon objects to be way too big: can JSon ignore certain JPA properties?

Tags: json, hibernate, jpa, spring-mvc

I have a JPA entity which is as follows:

```
@Entity
@DynamicUpdate
public class Message {

    @NotNull
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Member sender;

    @NotNull
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Member recipient;

    @NotNull
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss")
    private Date sendDate;

    private boolean messageRead;

    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 5, max = 500)
    @Column(length = 500)
    private String message;

    //Getter/Setters omitted

}
```

From a Spring MVC controller, I am returning a JSon array/collection to the browser as follows:

```
List<Message>
```

The issue I have is that each instance of Message has a `Member sender` property and a `Member recipient` property and the Member class itself has many relationships: collections etc.

The browser ends up clogged up with an huge JSon graph of objects/relationships.

**All I would like to do is ignore the `sender` and `recipient` properties in JSon (Those properties are set in the java layer anyway). Is that possible?**

**If that is not possible, what is the recommended practice in order to avoid the problem I described above?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried annotating the class with @JsonIgnoreProperties?

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"sender", "recipient"})
public class Message {
```

Comment: Hi Clav. Not bad actually!! Do you know of any way I can externalize this configuration and avoid putting it on my JPA entity?